# How to compare JSON Array key value's strings in each dictionary to see if they contain NSUserDefault strings and return JSON Dictionary matches

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

I'm a beginner and this subject is difficult for me to understand.  Any code help would be appreciated.

Main UITableView contains all recipe objects from a local JSON file.

Second UITableView contains all ingredient's values from every recipe in the JSON file where the user can select ingredients.  In this second tableview, I've used replaceOccurrencesOfString to shorten ingredient strings, as an example, from **1/2 tablespoon of salt** to **salt**.  Selected ingredients are stored in NSUserDefaults.

I need to be able to filter the recipes displayed on the main tableview to show only those recipes that contain ingredients the user selected in the second tableview.  The ingredients stored in NSUserDefaults can't be exact matches to those in the JSON file because of the replaceOccurrencesOfString used in the second tableview.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?  I don't even know where to begin.

Local JSON file:

```
{
      "locations": [

    { "name" : "Drop Biscuits and Sausage Gravy", "ingredients" : "Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespoons Baking Powder\n1/2 teaspoon Salt\nShortened for example”, "cookTime" : "PT30M" },

    { "name" : "Hot Roast Beef Sandwiches", "ingredients" : "12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)\n1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)\nShortened for example”, "cookTime" : "PT30M" },  
    //many more records.  only included 2 for example                            
      ]
    }
```

Main tableview - All recipes are returned in the UITableView like this:

```
@interface LocationsViewController () <UISearchResultsUpdating>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *RecipeArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *RecipeByIngredientsArray;

@end

@implementation LocationsViewController {
    NSArray *_locations;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


initWithTitle:(@"Kitchen") style:(UIBarButtonItemStylePlain) target:(self) action:(@selector(FilterButton:))];



    // Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
    JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"locations" withExtension:@"json"];

    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method
    UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocationsViewSearchResultsNavController"];

    // Our instance of UISearchController will use searchResults
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];


    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = true;

    // Load the data on a background queue...
    // As we are using a local file it's not really necessary, but if we were connecting to an online URL then we'd need it
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        self.RecipeArray = [jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile:url];
        // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
});

}

// Just before showing the LocationDetailViewController, set the selected Location object
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    LocationDetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    vc.location = [self.RecipeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //self.searchController.active = false;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      NSInteger tag = 120;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239/255.0 green:239/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIView  *whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-12, cell.contentView.frame.size.height-15)];
    CGFloat colors[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};//cell color white
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors);
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
    {if (cell.tag !=120) {cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedView];
         [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedView];
        cell.tag = tag;}}

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


#pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

    Location *location = [self.RecipeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//*****recall NSUserDefaults works, but not sure how to compare*******    
    NSMutableArray* array1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selections"];
    NSLog(@"-----------selections-----------%@", array1);

    cell.textLabel.text = location.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = location.cookTime;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"recipeicon2.png"];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return 100;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.RecipeArray count];
}


}

@end
```

Second tableview:

```
@interface FilterViewController () <UISearchResultsUpdating>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *IngredientsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *selectedRowObjects;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *selectedRows;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selections;

@end

@implementation FilterViewController {
    NSArray *_locations;


}


- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

    //self.selections = [NSMutableArray array];

    self.selections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selections"]];
    if(self.selections == nil){
        self.selections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

   //_myMtableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
    JSONLoaderIngreds *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoaderIngreds alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"locations" withExtension:@"json"];

    // There's no transition in our storyboard to our search results tableview or navigation controller
    // so we'll have to grab it using the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method
    UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterViewSearchResultsNavController"];

    // Our instance of UISearchController will use searchResults
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    // The searchcontroller's searchResultsUpdater property will contain our tableView.
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = true;


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        _locations = [jsonLoader ingredientsFromJSONFile:url];
        // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        });

    _selectedRows = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

}

// Just before showing the LocationViewController, set the selected Location object
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    LocationsViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    vc.location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


#pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        //the below code will allow multiple selection
    if ([self.selections containsObject:cell.textLabel.text])
    {
        [self.selections removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.selections addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"***************Selected Ingredients**************** %@", _selections);
    NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [userdefaults setObject:_selections forKey:@"selections"];
    [userdefaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"-------------NSUserDefaults------------%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);



}

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FilterCell"];



    cell.textLabel.text = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingredientsicon3232.png"];

       if ([self.selections containsObject:cell.textLabel.text])
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
       }
       else
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

       }
       return cell;
   }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_locations count];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON filter or processed and stored in NSDictionary

and then you need to study all the tableview delegate

finally display in table view